# SQL Programming combining 4 rows into 1 and adding 3 columns

Tags: sql

I have a table called AllData. This table has a column called UTCTimethat which has time in every 15 mins, the time start and end time are the following:

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime,
        @EndTime datetime,
        @Timeframe int,
        @ByHour bit = 1;

SET @Timeframe = CAST(700 * RAND() AS int);
SET @Timeframe = CASE WHEN @Timeframe = 0 THEN 1 ELSE @Timeframe END

SET @StartTime = dateadd(hh, -1 * @Timeframe, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(14), getutcdate(), 121) + '00' AS datetime));
SET @EndTime = dateadd(hh, @Timeframe, @StartTime);
```

UTCTimethat

```
2013-06-24 23:00:00.000
2013-06-24 23:15:00.000
2013-06-24 23:30:00.000
2013-06-24 23:45:00.000
```

Another column is called Values

```
31.2775
37.2275
37.595
35.0975
```

The problem is: I want to check if there is a NULL or 0 value in an hourly time span! Basically, I want a query that display a new column that is 1 hour time and next to it two columns NoData, Zero Data
Just like this

```
1 hourTime                                         NoData  ZeroData

2013-06-24 23:00:00.000 - 2013-06-24 23:45:00.000  0       0
```

NoData and ZeroData values are 0 because based on the Values column I don't have Null or 0 Data.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, there can be zero or more entries in AllData for any given 15 minute increment of time (UTCTimethat) and each entry will have a greater than zero value (Values)?

Comment: In the Values column the values can be NUll, 0, Or any value greater than 0.

Comment: For example: the values in the Values column can be: 0, (NUll), 20, 12 so in this case Nodata Column should be 1 for that hour and ZeroData should also be 1 for that hour.

Comment: So there is an entry for every 15 minute increment and the value can be null or zero or greater?  And you want to identify (per hour) the number of nulls and 0's that appear if there are any?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi Chad, I am using SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do this but here's one way:

```
select cast(datepart(yyyy, UTCTimethat) as varchar(4)) + '-' +
   cast(datepart(mm, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + '-' +
   cast(datepart(dd, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + ' ' +
   cast(datepart(hh, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + ':00:000 - ' +
   cast(datepart(yyyy, UTCTimethat) as varchar(4)) + '-' +
   cast(datepart(mm, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + '-' +
   cast(datepart(dd, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + ' ' +
   cast(datepart(hh, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + ':45:000' as HourTime,
   sum(case when Values is null then 1 else 0 end) as NoData,
   sum(case when Values = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ZeroData
from AllData
where isnull(Values, 0) = 0
group by cast(datepart(yyyy, UTCTimethat) as varchar(4)) + '-' +
   cast(datepart(mm, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + '-' +
   cast(datepart(dd, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + ' ' +
   cast(datepart(hh, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + ':00:000 - ' +
   cast(datepart(yyyy, UTCTimethat) as varchar(4)) + '-' +
   cast(datepart(mm, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + '-' +
   cast(datepart(dd, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + ' ' +
   cast(datepart(hh, UTCTimethat) as varchar(2)) + ':45:000'
```

Comment: Mr. Cook, thank you so much for this code. I am actually doing some modification and if you are interested I can send you what I am doing. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Mr. Cook, can I ask one more question? I just want something in the query since the data has no NULL values at all.

Comment: If there are no null values then why are you counting them?

Comment: You are correct! Actually I want to compare the values in the 1 hour time span, if there are any constant values then just display the number of the constant values (should be between 0 and 4) for example if the value at 2013-05-4 10:30 has the same value at 2013-05-4 10:15 then should be 1 in the NoValue column. basically, compare the value to the previous value in the 15 mins span. Thank you.

Comment: I just posted the question, if you want, please take a look at it. Thank you.This is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347361/sql-query-compare-values-in-per-15-minutes-and-display-the-result-per-hour