# SQL Query Compare values in per 15 minutes and display the result per hour

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I have a table with 2 columns. UTCTime and Values.
The UTCTime is in 15 mins increment. I want a query that would compare the value to the previous value in one hour span and display a value between 0 and 4 depends on if the values are constant. In other words there is an entry for every 15 minute increment and the value can be constant so I just need to check each value to the previous one per hour.

For example

```
+---------|-------+
| UTCTime | Value |
------------------|
|   12:00 |  18.2 |
|   12:15 |  87.3 |
|   12:30 | 55.91 |
|   12:45 | 55.91 |
|    1:00 |  37.3 |
|    1:15 |  47.3 |
|    1:30 |  47.3 |
|    1:45 |  47.3 |
|    2:00 |  37.3 |
+---------|-------+
```

In this case, I just want a Query that would compare the 12:45 value to the 12:30 and 12:30 to 12:15 and so on. Since we are comparing in only one hour span then the constant values must be between 0 and 4 (O there is no constant values, 1 there is one like in the example above)

The query should display:

```
+----------+----------------+
| UTCTime  | ConstantValues |
----------------------------|
| 12:00    | 1              |
|  1:00    | 2              |
+----------|----------------+
```

I just wanted to mention that I am new to SQL programming.
Thank you.

See SQL fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/179cf8)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am not sure what RDBMS means. I am using T-SQL and SSMS.

Comment: That's what I was after, 2008/2012?

Comment: SSMS 2012. Thank you.

Comment: RDBMS == Relational database Management System. In your case SQL Server 2012

Comment: Thank you nurdglaw. I guessed RDBMS had something to do SSMS :)

Comment: Could you explain your desired results, I'm confused by why 1:00 = 2, and in what case you'd get 0 or 4.

Comment: Sure, 1:00 is 2 because comparing  1:45 to 1:30 is a constant data (both are 47.3) then comparing 1:30 to 1:15 there is another constant value (47.3) this is how it is 2. 0 is when all values per hour are different. 4 if all values are the same per hour.

Comment: So 3 would be the max, right?  if `1:45 = 1:30`  then 1, if `1:45 = 1:30 = 1:15` then 2, and if `1:45 = 1:30 = 1:15 = 1:00` then 3? Or are you starting at 2:00 to 1:45 down to 1:00?

Comment: I am starting at 2 and going down to 1. Starting at 1:45 and going down to 1 would be 45 mins, and I want the result per hour :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the query you need and a [working solution](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5bf99/5) Note: I changed the timeframe to 24 hrs

```
       ;with SourceData(HourTime, Value, RowNum)
  as
  (
    select 
      datepart(hh, UTCTime) HourTime, 
      Value, 
      row_number() over (partition by datepart(hh, UTCTime) order by UTCTime) RowNum
    from foo
    union 
    select 
        datepart(hh, UTCTime) - 1 HourTime, 
        Value,
        5
    from foo
    where datepart(mi, UTCTime) = 0
  )
  select cast(A.HourTime as varchar) + ':00' UTCTime, sum(case when A.Value = B.Value then 1 else 0 end) ConstantValues
  from SourceData A
   inner join SourceData B on A.HourTime = B.HourTime and
                           (B.RowNum = (A.RowNum - 1))
  group by cast(A.HourTime as varchar) + ':00'
```

Comment: If you change 2:00 to 47.3 this does not work:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee1c5/1/0

Comment: Mine starts from 1:45 and goes to 1. Let me change the query little bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(UTCTime,':',1) as time,value, count(*)-1 as total
from foo group by value,time having total >= 1;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/179cf8/11)

Answer (score 0):

Mine isn't much different from Vasanth's, same idea different approach.

The idea is that you need recursion to carry it out simply.  You could also use the LEAD() function to look at rows ahead of your current row, but in this case that would require a big case statement to cover every outcome.

```
;WITH T
AS (
        SELECT a.UTCTime,b.VALUE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.UTCTime ORDER BY b.UTCTime DESC)'RowRank'
        FROM (SELECT * 
              FROM  #Table1 
              WHERE DATEPART(MINUTE,UTCTime) = 0
              )a
        JOIN #Table1 b
           ON b.UTCTIME BETWEEN a.UTCTIME AND DATEADD(hour,1,a.UTCTIME)
   )
 SELECT T.UTCTime, SUM(CASE WHEN T.Value = T2.Value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 FROM T 
 JOIN T T2
   ON T.UTCTime = T2.UTCTime 
    AND T.RowRank = T2.RowRank -1
 GROUP BY T.UTCTime
```

If you run the portion inside the `;WITH T AS ( )` you'll see that gets us the hour we're looking at and the values in order by time.  That is used in the recursive portion below by joining to itself and evaluating each row compared to the next row (hence the `RowRank - 1`) on the `JOIN`.