# SQL Query for Null, Zero, and Constant Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query and I just want to modify it (This query is not written by me).

```
SELECT  CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-'
        + CAST(DATEPART(mm, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-'
        + CAST(DATEPART(dd, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' '
        + CAST(DATEPART(hh, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':00:000 - '
        + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-'
        + CAST(DATEPART(mm, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-'
        + CAST(DATEPART(dd, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' '
        + CAST(DATEPART(hh, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':45:000' AS HourTime ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ElapsedValue IS NULL THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS NoData ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ElapsedValue = 0 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS ZeroData
FROM    tblLive_TrendLog_15Min
WHERE   ISNULL(ElapsedValue, 0) = 0
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-'
        + CAST(DATEPART(mm, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-'
        + CAST(DATEPART(dd, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' '
        + CAST(DATEPART(hh, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':00:000 - '
        + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-'
        + CAST(DATEPART(mm, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-'
        + CAST(DATEPART(dd, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' '
        + CAST(DATEPART(hh, UTCTimeStamp) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':45:000'
```

When I run this query, it is going to display:

```
HourlyTime                          ZeroData       NULL    
2013-6-8 23:00:000 - 2013-6-8 23:45:000 0   40    
2013-6-8 3:00:000 - 2013-6-8 3:45:000   0   52    
2013-6-8 7:00:000 - 2013-6-8 7:45:000   0   52    
2013-6-9 3:00:000 - 2013-6-9 3:45:000   0   52    
2013-6-9 4:00:000 - 2013-6-9 4:45:000   0   52    
2010-1-1 12:00:000 - 2010-1-1 12:45:000 0   36    
2010-1-1 13:00:000 - 2010-1-1 13:45:000 0   27    
2010-1-1 15:00:000 - 2010-1-1 15:45:000 0   30
```

Basically it is calculating the zero and null values per hour. If you want to know more about it this is the link:
[SQL Programming combining 4 rows into 1 and adding 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327835/sql-programming-combining-4-rows-into-1-and-adding-3-columns)

Now, I just want to add another column to that query that would calculate 
if there are any constant values then just display the number of the constant values (should be between 0 and 3) for example if the value at 2013-05-4 10:30 has the same value at 2013-05-4 10:15 then should be 1 in the ConstantData column. basically, compare the value to the previous value every 15 minutes.

Comment: How is this different from: your earlier question? [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347361/sql-query-compare-values-in-per-15-minutes-and-display-the-result-per-hour)

Comment: Please ignore this question! I am working on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a duplicate question, but just wanted to point out that with SQL 2012 you could greatly simplify your query with the FORMAT function:

```
SELECT  FORMAT(UTCTimeStamp ,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:000 - yyyy-MM-dd hh:45:000 ')AS HourTime ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ElapsedValue IS NULL THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS NoData ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ElapsedValue = 0 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS ZeroData
FROM    tblLive_TrendLog_15Min
WHERE   ISNULL(ElapsedValue, 0) = 0
GROUP BY FORMAT(UTCTimeStamp ,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:000 - yyyy-MM-dd hh:45:000 ')
```